# Better off with a power fill and ground fill?

Tags: power

I have a simple 2 layer set of boards that all interconnect such that the top board is a good 12" away from the bottom board that is the power source.  I neglected to make my power trace wider than the others and you can definitely see things dimming on the board that is farthest away.  I am running at 3.3V using 74HC series chips.

I'm wondering if it is better to just create a 3.3V power fill on the top layer and a ground fill on the bottom layer. My boards are being made at JLCPCB and the PCB thickness is the standard 1.6mm.  Or should I keep the ground fill and use larger traces for the power rail?

Comment: How many layers do you have? A fill doesn't really do too much on a 2-layer board, but when you have 4 or more layers they're extremely useful.

Comment: Currently just a 2 layer board

Comment: Unless this board is huge it's probably 1-2 dollars extra for 4 layers. Decide if it's worth your time to do a better job routing on 2 layers or add power/ground planes and pay slightly more. Usually for small prototypes I do 4 layers since my time is worth more then $1.50 an hour, but of course if you're ordering thousands it's worth it to spend an hour extra if it saves you 1 dollar per board.

Comment: So basically, the "best" way to manage power distribution on something like this is to go to a 4 layer board and have a power and ground plane, connect all power and gnd pads to those planes with vias and then route the other signal lines normally on the top and bottom layers

Comment: Given that your PCB is being manufactured by JLCPCB with a standard thickness of 1.6mm, both options should be feasible.

Comment: The planes will help with EMC and SI as well.

Comment: Yes the best is two planes and the external layers for signals. But as user185 said above, it depends on cost management if any. With 74HC logic you don't use a lot of power so even with very small traces it should work. What is dimming on the board? LED? How much current  does it use? Large traces should be ok too of they match maximum current draw.

Answer (score 3):

There are as many reasons to choose a layout, as there are layout strategies.  And there are about as many of those are there are PCBs in existence.  It's impossible to go into complete detail here, but the general considerations are:

- DC resistance, which seems to be your immediate problem
- Signal quality, functional EMI (avoiding self-interference)
- EMC, minimizing interference emitted from the unit; tolerating external interference incident upon the unit

DC resistance is achieved by using thicker and wider conductors.  Simply remember to set trace widths properly (yeah, duh, I know..).  This can be done fairly independently of the rest, so I will set it aside here.

AC is where all the interesting stuff happens.  There is no lower impedance conductor than a ground plane.  Or, in general, a thick enough metal surface, against which electromagnetic fields reflect, or get absorbed into, being completely (for some margin of "complete"; a factor of many thousands is practical) blocked between the two sides of that surface.

The thinner and more open a network of conductors is, the more fields swirl around them, and the more signal couples between them.  First and foremost, you must ensure that signals do not interfere with each other, or the unit simply can't work in general -- or it can most of the time, but an unlucky data pattern rolls through, enough signal bounce and propagation delays conspire to flip the bit value of some other signals, and, the house of cards falls apart, the CPU is reading trash data, memory's been overwritten with faulty bits, whatever.

More complex fields lead to more complex impedances, including self-impedance (the current flowing in response to a given voltage signal e.g. step change, or any combination thereof), and coupling between lines.  Both affect signal quality, causing bounce (and potentially re-triggering of clock inputs, misreading of data levels within the setup-hold sampling window, etc.), degradation of noise margins (spikes on a signal bringing its level closer to pin input logic threshold), etc.

We generally operate with the assumption that ground and VDD are reliable references everywhere in the circuit, but we especially violate this assumption if we make them thin, extended networks intermingled with signal traces; let alone if a bus of signals even takes up more cross-section than the supplies themselves (consider a multiconductor cable with, say, 8 data lines and only one VDD and GND wire each; the signals have a 8:2 leverage over the supplies and considerable common-mode currents will flow on the cable).

So we strongly prefer, and encourage, pouring a solid ground everywhere, and connecting it densely through connectors (every other pin, say).

We still need to route signals and power somehow, so, on a 2-layer board, we might prefer one side GND, route on the other layer, and interrupt GND as infrequently as possible with short jumper traces, crossing under top-side busses only where required.

Since SMTs are cheap and plentiful, and easy to use (and if you're not using them, it's strongly encouraged; SOICs aren't much harder to assemble than DIPs, and don't be afraid to get tools to help out if you have shaky hands, poor eyesight, etc.; electronics should be enjoyed by everyone!), there's typically a lot of stuff already occupying the top surface (we likewise prefer one-side-loaded assembly to save on assembly cost/hassle), so that puts ground on the bottom.

Note this requires we leave ample routing space between local groups of components / subcircuits.  Anywhere traces cross (or traces go under an SMT footprint, intersecting the row of pads), there is a negative space created, in both layers on the board, where no ground is present.  We must minimize the loop perimeter and enclosed area of these openings, to maintain the low impedance we have assumed at the start of our work.

We can increase density a little bit, avoiding some layer transitions (reducing via count, and the area thus taken up), by routing traces and buses on the bottom side, so long as we ensure ground pours on top of them.  That means these buses should avoid top-side components (because they necessarily create open negative space in the top-side pour).  We stitch the two layers together using vias, particularly in at least three out of the four corners at a crossing, and also periodically alongside traces, at peninsulas and islands created by crossings, bends and loops in the placement and routing, and perhaps a few spread around open areas (GND over GND, away from any traces or components).

The act of stitching unites the top and bottom pours, so that a low impedance solid conductor is obtained.

Generally speaking, we want about half the layers dedicated to routing, and half to ground planes, or supernodes connected thereto.

By stitching a 2-layer board poured on both sides, we get effectively one middle layer *on average*, with routing on both sides of that "average middle" (but with many caveats; as above: avoid routing top and bottom together in the same region).

If we go up to four layers, we can allocate the middle pair as GND and VDD (VDD being well coupled to GND by the plane-to-plane capacitance*, further enforced by bypass caps scattered around.  And, because the plane pair acts as a nearly-ideal connection between points within it, those bypass caps don't need to be particularly close to any loads within it; do prioritize heavy, fast or peaky loads, like bus drivers, or a big MCU, or an SMPS section; but for casual 74HC logic and most light duty ASICs, don't worry about it too much.

*Actually a low impedance transmission line, but that's only relevant at frequencies comparable to the electrical length of the plane -- 100s MHz.  74HC doesn't draw harmonics much above this, so it's not a big deal.  The confined 2D-wave structure of the parallel planes can be relevant for high-speed applications (~GHz!), however.

And then for the 4-layer build, we have two layers free for routing, one partially obstructed by components (or both, plus perforations through both planes, if using lots of THT -- another reason to avoid them, the routing density and signal quality are limited for multiple reasons together!), the other free.  Or we can place components on both sides, if we don't mind the added cost, and need to push density very high (or even go to 6 layers or more, or blind vias to further improve density, etc.).

If about half the layers should be ground planes *or supernodes*, then about half of those in turn could be power supplies, again, as long as they are well bypassed.  For the 4-layer design, that works out quite handily; and most of the time, we only need one (say 3.3 or 5V) net to cover most things, and we can route whatever's left (12V or +/-15V or etc. might be just for peripherals anyway), or divide the plane into regional domains (e.g. 3.3V here, AVDD there, 5 or 12V elsewhere..).

So, it would be great if we had a power plane all the time.  Going back to the 2-layer case, we don't really have anywhere to put a power plane, right?

Well, let's consider the proposal of pouring power say on top, GND on bottom.

We still need to route somewhere, so no matter which layer we choose as preference, we're cutting up *something* important.  That's a pretty bad start.

And we don't have any way to stitch around slots/gaps in a plane, other than to add jumper vias and traces; we can't just stitch to another pour, it's a lot trickier than that.

We could still stitch the planes, and maintain good supply quality (low impedance vs. frequency), by placing bypass caps everywhere.  That doesn't do anything for DC, we still need to visually inspect it (there's no automated tool to check polygon *density* of connectivity, at least not one anywhere near affordable), and that's both prone to errors (you'll inevitably miss some narrow web, an isthmus of pour, connecting two important power areas, and now your board is cooking, and supplies drooping..), and fragile under modification (nudge a trace, boop, it snaps out from the GND-GND jumper structure it had been cradled in, now there's a gap somewhere else; are you going to remember to move *each one* every time?).  And even if we've kept track of all these changes, we're still using far more components (bypass caps), and dedicating layout area to GND/VDD stitching, and vias and bypass caps, to do what we could've done more or less equally well, with less effort, with a GND-pour-both-sides strategy and trace routed VDD.

There is one final advantage to trace-routed power: PDN (power distribution network) analysis.  Anywhere we have a trace over/surrounded by GND, in some reasonably consistent cross-sectional structure, we have a transmission line (TL), and at low frequencies, that TL has lumped-equivalent inductance and capacitance.  In particular, PDNs are low impedance so the series inductance is dominant.  You can figure ballpark 0.5nH per mm of trace length, give or take a geometry factor (it's lower when traces are wider; this is about the right figure for traces say 1/5 to 1/2 the board thickness).  With a point-to-point routing strategy, you can simply measure the trace length between points, convert to inductance, and craft a, reasonably representative, PDN model and test it in SPICE (or, once you develop enough understanding of the rules of network theory, hand-wave the design by eye!).

Answer (score 1):

It's very reasonable to do a ground fill on one side and power fill on the other.